# Question word used as a noun

Tags: gramática, ortografía, significado

Buenas tardes,

En algunos programas españoles que he visto, a menudo se dice "No tienes *por qué*" o "No tiene *dónde* ir." He aprendido que las palabras "por qué", "dónde", etc. se usan para preguntas, pero me parece que en estas frases se usan para decir "You don't have a reason" y "He doesn't have a place to go."

¿Cómo funciona este empleo de "por qué" y "dónde"? ¿Siquiera lo estoy oyendo correctamente? :) Como oí esas frases en vez de verlas escritas, me gustaría saber si la ortografía tiene sentido. También querría saber si hay otros casos comunes en los cuales se usan los pronombres interrogativos así, y qué significados tienen.

Espero que me entiendan. ¡Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende un poco.

Los interrogativos son pronombres (*qué, quién<sub>es</sub>, cuál, cuánto<sub>/a/os/as</sub>*), adjetivos (*cúyo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>*, hoy antiguo) y adverbios (*dónde y cuándo*)<sup>1</sup> que reemplazan algo desconocido o no revelado y son siempre tónicos: por eso se los tilda siempre.

Si alguien dice algo como

- No tiene dónde ir
- No te preocupes, tengo dónde alojarme.

Hay varias formas de entenderlo gramáticalmente, pero siempre se entiende igual.  Puede ser una elipsis, por ejemplo, *No tiene dónde <sub>(puede)</sub> ir*, o puede ser un infinitivo con sujeto implicado como *Tengo dónde alojarme<sub>1ST.SING.</sub>*.

A veces forman parte de cláusulas bastante largas, así que no pienses que solo aparecen al final de una frase:

- Mi entrenadora me dijo qué era lo que necesitaba hacer para llegar a los JJ.OO.

Nota también la diferencia entre varias posibilidades:

- Mi entrenadora mi dijo qué hacía algo mejor.
  <sup>My coach told me **what** I was doing something better</sup>
- Mi entrenadora mi dijo que hacía algo mejor.
  <sup>My coach told me **that** I was doing something better</sup>
- Mi entrenadora mi dijo que hiciese<sub>/ra</sub> algo mejor
  <sup>My coach told me **to do** something better</sup>

En estas cláusulas, no se suele usar el modo subjuntivo.

Tu ejemplo con *por qué* es más complicado porque se puede entenderlo de dos formas que no son posibles de distinguir en el habla:

- No tienes *por qué*. <sub>(pronombre interrogativo con preposición)</sub>
- No tienes *porqué*. <sub>(sustantivo masculino)</sub>

En el primer ejemplo (con espacio) se sobreentiende una elipsis de algo.  *No tienes por qué [llamarme|hacerlo|entregarlas]*.  Pero en el segundo (sin espacio), hay un sustantivo que equivale «razón», es decir, *No tienes una razón [por la que…]*.  La verdad es que no cambia la interpretación así que puedes entender como quieras.

---

<sup>1. Personalmente, considero que *dónde* y *cuándo* puede considerarse pronombres cuando, por ejemplo, se les entiende como *qué lugar* o *qué tiempo* en vez de *a/de/en qué lugar* o *a/durante/para/por qué tiempo/hora*, pero estoy divagando...</sup>

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan completa. Déjeme intentar: "Iría a la biblioteca, pero no hay por qué." Es decir: "I would go to the library, but there's no reason to." ¿Correcto? Además, ¿puede Ud. dar un ejemplo de elipsis con los otros interrogativos, o dirigirme a dónde puedo encontrarlo? (¿He escrito eso correctamente?)

Answer (score 1):

*Por qué*: usamos tilde y separamos ambas palabras cuando deseamos formular preguntas.

> ¿Por qué viniste? ¿Por qué lo hiciste?, etc.

*Porque*: es el que responde al por qué.

> **P:** ¿por qué viniste? **R**: porque tengo ganas de verte.
>
> **P:** ¿por qué lo hiciste? **R**: porque estaba aburrido.

---

*dónde*: para tratar de especificar el lugar.

> ¿*Dónde* estamos? ¿En *dónde* me debo sentar? ¿A *dónde* le llevaban?

*donde*: usado una vez especificado el lugar.

> La calle *donde* nací; La tierra por *donde* pisa; Las figuras pueden superponerse, de *donde* se deduce su igualdad.

---

Si decimos *no tienes porque*, estamos explicando lo que ya se preguntó. Escribiendo *no tienes por qué* es lo que se conoce como *you don't have why to...*

*no tiene dónde ir* va con tilde pues no se ha especificado el lugar. (No porque lleve un *no* implica la necesidad de la tilde, en realidad también podríamos tener *¿tiene dónde ir?* y también se ve que el lugar no está especificado en la pregunta.)

Comment: Gracias, ya entiendo la distinción entre "por qué" vs. "porque", etc. ¿Puede Ud. dar un caso en que se usa "No tienes porque" y uno en que se usa "No tienes por qué"? Me parece que en las frases que mencioné encima, la palabra "por qué" tiene el significado de "reason" en vez de "why," y "dónde" significa "place." ¿Tiene sentido esto, o me confundo?

Answer (score -2):

Hay 4 diferentes palabras:
Porqué / porque / por qué / por que

pueden sonar igual, pero cada una tiene un significado y uso diferente.
Aqui te dejo el link de la real academia española:
http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que